# psycopg2.Data Error: invalid input syntax for integer:" "

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Hi..i tried to search for an entry in my table that holds both text and integer values..my code works well on sqlite3 database...but throws Data Error on Postgresql database..

```
import psycopg2
class database:

    def __init__(self):

        self.con=psycopg2.connect("dbname='book_store' user='postgres' password='5283' host='localhost' port='5432' ")
        self.cur=self.con.cursor()
        self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists books(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,author TEXT NOT NULL,year integer NOT NULL,isbn integer NOT NULL UNIQUE)")
        self.con.commit()

    def insert(self,title,author,year,isbn):
      try:
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO books(title,author,year,isbn) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)",(title,author,year,isbn))
        self.con.commit()
      except:
          #print("already exists..")
          pass

    def view(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
        rows=self.cur.fetchall()
        print(rows)

    def search(self,title="",author="",year="",isbn=""):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title=%s or author=%s or year=%s or isbn=%s",(title,author,year,isbn))
        row=self.cur.ferchall()
        print(row)

db=database()
#db.insert("The Naughty","AparnaKumar",1995,234567654)
db.view()
db.search(year=1995)
```

[image: psycopg2.Data Error: invalid input syntax for integer:" "]

Comment: Pass the isbn as null not as empty string

Comment: ISBNs are either 10 or 13 characters in length, which the 10-digit version having the potential to start with a zero. Not sure using `integer` for the data type in your table is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
def search(self, title=None, author=None, year=None, isbn=None):
    self.cursor.execute("""
        select * 
        from books 
        where 
            (title = %(title)s or %(title)s is null)
            and
            (author = %(author)s or %(author)s is null)
            and
            (year = %(year)s or %(year)s is null)
            and
            (isbn = %(isbn)s or %(isbn)s is null)
        """,
        {'title': title, 'author': author, 'year': year, 'isbn': isbn}
    )
```

Comment: That would likely solve the issue, but maybe explain why? Otherwise this is a code-only answer.